# How to emulate <F11> press on startup in vimrc

Tags: vim

`<F11>` makes it full screen in ubuntu (I changed the settings and chose show the menus for a window In the window's title bar rather than in the menu bar) and hides the global menu panel (at the top with the battery and wifi symbols). I didn't want to press `<F11>` every single time I opened `gvim` so what do I have to write in `.vimrc` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mappings and Vimscript commands that you can put into your `~/.vimrc` are only for scripting Vim itself; you cannot directly control your environment with it. The only way is through launching an external command (via `:!` or `:call system(...)`, for example `wmctrl` with the right arguments. Alternatively, you could modify the shortcut / command that launches GVIM to include this maximization, so you don't need to "break out" from inside Vim.

I'm using the `:Fullscreen` command of the [shell.vim - Improved integration between Vim and its environment](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3123) plugin; it works well on Windows and Gnome. You can launch that automatically by putting `Fullscreen` into your `~/.gvimrc`.

Comment: There's also [vullscreen](https://github.com/KabbAmine/vullScreen.vim) for GNU/Linux, whose sole aim is to provide the full-screen feature.